# GCC : left shift operator on unsigned long long int does not work when shift is greater than 32?

Tags: c, gcc, printf, bit-manipulation, shift

Considering this simple example :

```
unsigned long long int my_int=0b10100110;
printf("%.64B\n",my_int<<40);
```

Why is the output zero ? `unsigned long long int` is used (sizeof = 8), 64 bits machine, OS : Fedora 37, gcc (GCC) 12.2.1 20221121 (Red Hat 12.2.1-4), and compilation with or without the m64 flag.

Comment: My compiler doesn't accept the %B format specifier, but if I print in hex, it works: `a60000000000`. So the shift works, its the printf() that fails. @KamilCuk seems to have found the solution.

Comment: Have you seen the `warning: format ‘%B’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long long unsigned int’` ?

Comment: Perhaps, ```%B``` ---> ```%llu```.

Comment: Ok. %B accepts only 32 bits integers and not 64 bits.

Comment: Not aware of `%B` – is that standard at all? If it follows the usual pattern of other format specifiers you might try `%llB` to indicate `unsigned long long` to the compiler...

Comment: @Aconcagua. Thanks a lot. This is the solution. To complete your comment : `.64llB`, to have leading 0.

Comment: @Aconcagua `"%B"` is not standard.  Perhaps in upcoming C2x.

Comment: @Stef1611 Ref:  print in [binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111928/2410359) (or using standard C in [any base](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641674/2410359)).

Answer (score 3):

For starters this format of an integer constant

```
0b10100110
```

is not standard.

Binary integer constants are valid in C++.

Also the function `printf` does not support the conversion specifier `B`.

In any case to output an object of the type `unsigned long long int` you need to use length modifier `ll` before the conversion specifier.

Instead you could use a hexadecimal integer constant like for example

```
unsigned long long int my_int = 0xA6;
```

and output it like

```
printf("%#.8llx\n",my_int<<40);
```

In this case the output will look like

```
0xa60000000000
```

Or as **@chux - Reinstate Monica** correctly pointed in the comment to the answer you can use the following call

```
printf("%#0.8llx\n",my_int<<40);
```

to output the prefix `0x` when the corresponding argument is equal to `0`.

Comment: When `my_int == 0`, output is "000000000000".  (no prefix)  Consider `"0x%016llX\n"`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Just a comment, `%B` is not standard but it works on my gcc version. That is important in my case. Waiting for C2x ...

Comment: @Stef1611 Try to prefix it with the length modifier ll.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow. Done and it works. See my last comment in my question.